Canonical proof of isomorphisms like $\operatorname{Hom}(V \otimes V, V \otimes V) \cong V^* \otimes V^* \otimes V \otimes V$
$\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$
$\def\F{\mathbb{F}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left(#1\right)}$
$\def\tu{\tilde{u}}$
$\def\tv{\tilde{v}}$
$\def\vx{\vec{x}}$
$\def\vy{\vec{y}}$
To show that $\Hom(V,V) \cong V^* \otimes V \cong V \otimes V^*$ ($V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\F$ and $V^*$ is its dual space) we can use
$$
L \vx (\tu) = B_L(\tu,\vx)={B_L}'(\vx,\tu)
$$
where $L: V\to V$, $B_L: V^* \times V \to \F$, ${B_L}'$ is the transpose of $B_L$, $\vx$ denotes a vector and $\tu$ denotes a covector. This equation establishes a bijective map from $\Hom(V,V)$ to $V \otimes V^*$ or $V^* \otimes V$.
Is there a similar method by which we can show that
$$
\Hom(V \otimes V, V \otimes V) \cong V^* \otimes V^* \otimes V \otimes V ?
$$
On the r.h.s I have a multilinear form $M: V \times V \times V^* \times V^* \to \F$. On the l.h.s I have a map from a bilinear form $A: V^* \times V^* \to \F$ to another bilinear form $B: V^* \times V^* \to \F$. It is not obvious how to express $A \mapsto B$. $V \otimes V \cong \Hom(V^*,V)$ so perhaps if $L_A:V^* \to V$ is the linear map that corresponds to $A$,
$$B(\tv_1,\tv_2)= L_A\tu_1\otimes L_A\tu_2(\tv_1,\tv_2)=L_A\tu_1(\tv_1)
L_A\tu_2(\tv_2)=M(L_A \tu_1, L_A \tu_2, \tv_1, \tv_2).$$
It is not clear to me if this is a valid construction or that this map is bijective. Can someone provide a better approach?

There is an elegant answer posted by @krm2233 ; unfortunately, because of my poor grasp of the subject, I cannot follow their proof.
Going back to Multilinear Algebra by Werner Greub, in Section 1.16 there is the definition of the tensor product of linear maps. He starts with $L_1,L_2 \in \Hom(V,V)$ (my notation) and then defines a bilinear map
$$
\vx \times \vy \to L_1 \vx \otimes L_2 \vy
$$
which, given the universal property of $\otimes$, means that there exists a linear map $M: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$ such that
$$
M(\vx \otimes \vy) = L_1 \vx \otimes L_2 \vy.
$$
Now there is a correspondence $(L_1,L_2) \mapsto M$ and hence a bilinear map
$$
\Hom(V,V) \times \Hom(V,V) \to \Hom(V \otimes V, V \otimes V)
$$
from which a linear map
$$
\Hom(V,V) \otimes \Hom(V,V) \to \Hom(V \otimes, V \otimes V)
$$
can be induced.
Since $\Hom(V,V)\cong V^* \otimes V$ from this point it should be possible to establish that there exists a bijective linear map
$$
(V^* \otimes V) \otimes (V^* \otimes V) \to 
\Hom(V \otimes, V \otimes V)
$$
which proves that the two spaces are isomorphic (unfortunately Greub's proof of this proposition requires the use of a basis).

In my opinion at some point it becomes just tidier to use previously established results. In this case you can use from your introduction that $\operatorname{Hom}(V \otimes V, V \otimes V) \cong (V \otimes V)^* \otimes (V \otimes V)$, and it is left to prove that a) tensor products commute with taking duals, and b) tensor products are associative (both of which are not too hard). If, on the other hand you want to construct a bijection, then I would have to reflect on that myself ...

@ClemensB agreed, it is an established result. I am just trying to prove to myself that it works hence my attempt to construct a map between bilinear forms.

There are two morphisms from which you can build the maps you need:
(1) For any pair of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $\mathsf k$, there is a natural map
$$
c\colon V^*\otimes W \to \mathrm{Hom}(V,W).
$$
given by $f\otimes w \mapsto [v\mapsto f(v).w]$. Note that $V^* = \mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathsf k)$, and there is a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathsf k,W) \cong W$ given by sending $\lambda \colon \mathsf k \to W$ to $\lambda(1)\in W$, with inverse $w\mapsto \lambda_w$, where $\lambda_w(t)= tw$ for any $t \in \mathsf k$. Viewing $W$ as $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathsf k,W)$ the map $c$
$$
c\colon \mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathsf k)\otimes \mathrm{Hom}(\mathsf k,W)\to \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)
$$
is simply a special case of composition of linear maps. Now $c(f\otimes w) = \lambda_w \circ f$ is a composition of a pair of linear maps $V\to \mathsf k \to W$ and hence has rank (at most) 1. (This is also clear from the initial definition of $c$ of course). It follows that the image of $c$ is therefore the subspace of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ consisting of linear maps of finite rank:
Proposition: If $c\colon V^*\otimes W \to \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ is the canonical map defined above then $\text{im}(c)= \mathrm{Hom}^{fr}(V,W)\subseteq \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ is the subspace of linear maps of finite rank.
Proof:
We first show that $\mathrm{im}(c) \subseteq \mathrm{Hom}^{fr}(V,W)$. If $\theta$ is in $\text{im}(c)$ then for some $\delta_j \in V^*, w_j \in W$ ($1\leq j \leq k$) we must have
$$
\theta = c(\sum_{j=1}^k \delta_j\otimes w_j) = \sum_{j=1}^k \delta_j.w_j.
$$
But then for any $v \in V$ we must have $\theta(v) \in \text{span}\{w_j: 1\leq j \leq k\}$ and hence $\theta$ has rank at most $k$.  To see the reverse inclusion, suppose that $\varphi\colon V \to W$ has finite rank and let $\{f_1,\ldots,f_m\}$ be a basis of its image $\varphi(V)$. Then if $v \in V$ we may write $\varphi(v) = \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j(v).f_j$, and the scalars $\lambda_j(v)$ are uniquely determined because $\{f_1,\ldots,f_m\}$ is a basis of $\varphi(V)$. It follows that $v \mapsto \lambda_j(v)$ is a linear map and hence $\lambda_j \in V^*$ so that $\varphi = \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j.f_j = c(\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j\otimes f_j)$ is in the image of $c$ as required.
Remark: If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, and you pick a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $V$ and a basis $\{f_1,\ldots,f_m\}$ of $W$, then the matrix associated to any linear map $\varphi\colon V \to W$ using these bases is given by
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\varphi(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}f_i, \forall j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}.
$$
Now the space of $m\times n$ matrices has an obvious basis given by the matrices $E_{ij}$ which have all entries $0$ except for the $(ij)$th entry, which is $1$. These matrices therefore correspond to a basis of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$, and by considering ($\dagger$) it is not too hard to see that $E_{ij}$ corresponds to the map $\delta_j\otimes f_i$ where $\{\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_n\}$ is the basis of $V^*$ dual to $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. Thus the images of the tensor $\delta_j\otimes f_i$ in $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ are the linear maps corresponding to the standard basis of the space of matrices. This shows more concretely that $c$ is an isomorphism in the case where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional.
(2) The multiplication operation of the field $\mathsf k$ is a bilinear map $\mathsf k\times \mathsf k\to \mathsf k$. If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces, then this gives a natural map $m\colon V^*\otimes W^* \to (V\otimes W)^*$: if $\delta \in V^*$ and $\eta \in W^*$ then $(v,w)\mapsto \delta(v).\eta(w)$ is clearly a bilinear map. By the universal property of the tensor product, it therefore yields a linear map $V\otimes W \to \mathsf k$, that is, an element $\delta.\eta$ of $(V\otimes W)^*$. Now the map $(\delta,\eta)\to \delta.\eta$ is itself clearly bilinear and so induces the required map $m$ where $m(\delta\otimes \eta) = \delta.\eta$. When $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, it is easy to see using dual bases that the map $m$ is an isomorphism (and the same argument shows that in general it is injective).
(3) Finally, if $V$ is finite-dimensional, then so is $V\otimes V$, hence by (1) the map
$$
c_{V\otimes V}\colon (V\otimes V)^*\otimes(V\otimes V)\to \mathrm{Hom}(V\otimes V,V\otimes V)
$$ is an isomorphism. By (2) we have an isomorphism
$$
m\otimes 1_V \otimes 1_V\colon V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes V \to (V\otimes V)^*\otimes V \otimes V.
$$
Thus the composition $c_{V\otimes V} \circ (m\otimes 1_V\otimes 1_V)$ gives the desired isomorphism.

Thanks I am reading through your note; silly question: when you write $v\mapsto f(v).w$ or $m(\delta \otimes \eta)=\delta.\eta$ the $.$ denotes scalar multiplication right?

@TedBlack yes! Sorry, I probably wasn't consistent about that, but at least for $m$ it seemed better not to suppress the multiplication operation altogether as it is key operation that makes the map work!

My understanding is that $\lambda: {\sf k} \to W$ sends 1 to $w$  (denoted as $\lambda(1)$) and hence $V \to {\sf k} \to W$ is a map from $V$ to a one-dimensional subspace of $W$.  If $V$ is finite dimensional how is this converted to the entire space of linear maps?

@TedBlack I've updated my answer to give more details about why the image of $c$ is the linear maps of finite rank. Hopefully it helps!
